# Java array logic

Tags: java, arrays

My program needs to:

- Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of
  numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will
  be followed by at least one 7)
- Return 0 for no numbers

Example:

```
sum67({1, 2, 2}) → 5
sum67({1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7}) → 5
sum67({1, 1, 6, 7, 2}) → 4
```

I tried this but it doesn't work for the next 6 and 7

```
public int sum67(int[] nums) {
    int sixIndex=0;
    int sevenIndex=0;
    int sum = 0, flag=0;

    if(nums.length !=0) {
        for(int a=0; a<nums.length; a++) {
            if(nums[a] == 6 ) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 1) {
            for(int i =0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                if(nums[i] == 6) sixIndex= i;
                if(nums[i] == 7) sevenIndex = i;
            }

            for(int j = 0; j<nums.length; j++) {
                if(j == sixIndex) break;
                sum+=nums[j];
            }

            for(int k = sevenIndex+1; k<nums.length; k++) {
                if(k == sevenIndex) break;
                sum+=nums[k];
            }

        }

        else {
            for(int b = 0; b<nums.length; b++) {
                sum+=nums[b];
            }
        }
   }

   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework. It's an exercise from codingbat (http://codingbat.com/prob/p111327). StackOverflow is not a site where you get people to finish your homework for you; we need a specific question.

Comment: This reads like you just copy and pasted your homework here. Please show your attempt at this so far and explain what your actual question is.

Comment: Don't be lazy. Try this yourself. Throw yourself at the problem. Let your brain hurt. Struggle. Erase it all and try again. Try. Try. Try again. Don't let others deprive you of this learning experience by giving you the spoon fed answer.

Comment: i tried it but forget to write my efforts but before editing the question i got -6 :(. Now i have updated my question

Comment: @SycoUraz what problem you are facing

Comment: @SycoUraz `but dont work` tells us pretty much nothing about the actual problem you're encountering. Please be as detailed as possible in describing *how* it "dont work".

Answer (score 2):

This bit of code should do the trick. The variable c keeps track of whether we're between a 6-7 block.

```
class Potato
{
    int sum67(int arr[])
    {
        boolean c = false;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : arr)
        {
            if (x == 6)// stop adding
                c = true;
            else if (x == 7 && c)// start adding, but only when stopped
                c = false;
            else if (!c)// add only if not stopped
                sum += x;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**postscriptum**: when you start out coding, even the most simplest of things can be a hurdle. Be nice, guys.

Comment: @SycoUraz If you're not familiar with the condensed version of the for-loop, what it simply does is goes through each number in the array one by one, keeping the current number in the variable called x. It's equivalent to normal for-loop,

Comment: @xrish Giving him a code dump with the answer helps nobody, in my opinion. Arguably this does more harm than good.

Comment: @Kon I didn't ask for your opinion. This guy wanted some help. Arguably, pasting code to _any_ question could be harmful. A question's merit is not dependent on whether it references some obscure or complicated aspect of code. Just because a question seems simple to you does not automatically imply that it's simple for someone else.

Comment: No point being rude. The problem is not that the question is simple. The problem is that he posted code with bugs in it and you just dumped an answer on him. OK, great, he has an answer now. But he didn't learn anything. And you didn't correct his code or explain why his thinking was wrong. This website is about helping people write better code themselves, not about helping people get the right answer.

Comment: @xrisk i agree with you. This stackoverflow is not only for the experts its also for the beginers where they stuck while performing some tasks. I dont    know why everybody wants experts to post questions. If they dont like the answer or if it seens too simple then why they cannot simply ignore it and surf for questions they are interested in. "**Not everyone is perfect, even the high pointers were also in need before being expert**"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `j` and `k` loop you can use only one loop

```
 for(int j = 0; j<nums.length; j++){
        if(!((j>=sixIndex) && (j<=sevenIndex))) 
        sum +=nums[j];
  }
```